# Print Python pandas dataframe with aligned decimal points

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

For a pandas dataframe `df` the output of

```
print(df.round(decimals=3))
```

was

```
                     mean        sd      skew  ...       min       max count
est mean and sd   1.58895  0.494215  0.055769  ... -0.255506  3.210586  1000
est mean          1.59015  0.034379  0.092728  ...  1.485435  1.706782  1000
est sd           1.586303  0.492995  0.065619  ... -0.254994  3.336123  1000
```

How can I align the decimal points in the "mean" column?

Comment: try: `pandas.set_option('display.precision', 5)`

Answer (score 1):

import pandas as pd

## Your DataFrame (df) is already rounded with df.round(decimals=3)

## Convert numbers in the "mean" column to strings with aligned decimal points

df['mean'] = df['mean'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:,.3f}')

## Print the DataFrame

print(df)